# samsung galaxy tab gt-p 1000 wifi icon trouble

Tags: applications, wi-fi, root-access

My samsung galaxy tab gt-p 1000 is working fine. Previously the wifi icon on the top of the screen used to be a dot alongwith 4 semicircles of 60 degrees. Since last 3 days this icon has disappeared and two different icons alternately flash on original icon's place. Tab is stiil running ok.

Comment: What do the new icons look like? What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

As Dan asked:

> What do the new icons look like? What's your question?

I have had the same problem for the year i have had a LG-P925. The only way to resolve this is to reboot the phone. Since i rooted my phone, i go the app Quick Boot and put a widget button on my screen to reboot it. You will also realize that if you leave the wifi turned on and it doesn't connect, it might continue to keep your phone alive and drain the battery faster. I have used BETTERBATTERYstats app (free on xda developers site) to find out that it was not an app draining my battery, but the fact it fails to connect to the wifi because of this issue. i suggest rooting the phone and installing Quickboot and put a widget to reboot it. This happens to me once every other day.

I hope it helps you!